# Transfer printf to some variable

Tags: c, variables, bit

i have transfered elements of array to printf that **string/bits** which I need to transfer  to some **variable**, because i need to work then with this *text/string ( 01000001 )* and convert it to char (bits => char).

```
//main
bool bits2[8] = {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1};
printf("%c\n", decode_byte(bits2));

//function
char decode_byte(const bool bits[8]){
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<8; i++){
    printf("%d", bits[i]);
  }
  
  
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Code + console]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What result are you wanting to get?

Comment: You mean to return 'A' when your funcion decode {01000001}?

Comment: @Fawad yes I mean that.. Function which return 'A' from my printf in console or from array {01000001}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  bool bits2[8] = { 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1 };
  unsigned char c = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    c <<= 1;
    c |= bits2[i];
  }

  printf("%02x\n", c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`decode_byte` should just convert from binary representation to an actual integer:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char decode_byte(const bool bits[8]) {
    unsigned char c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        c = (c << 1) | bits2[i];
    }
    return c;
}

int main() {
    bool bits2[8] = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    printf("%c\n", decode_byte(bits2));
    return 0;
}
```

The program should output `A`, which is the ASCII character encoded as `65`, whose binary representation is `01000001`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//function
char decode_byte(const bool bits[8]){
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
      sum += (1<<i)*bits[7-i];
  }
  return (char)sum;
}
```

Read about ascii table. When sum is 65, its type converted value in ascii table is 'A'